# GAE datastore: RuntimeError when attempting to use python/NDB to read data written in Java/objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, objectify

I'm using appengine and datastore. I have two GAE modules sharing the same data. One module is running on the Java runtime and utilizes objectify to **write** data. The other runs on the Python runtime and is using NDB for data **read**.

One of my kinds contains a list of embedded entities. When I try to fetch entities from this kind (Python module) the following error is raised:

```
RuntimeError: StructuredProperty memberOf expected to find properties separated by periods at a depth of 1; received ['memberOf']
```

Here is how the Java/objectify mapping looks like:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Unindex
    private Set<TeamMembership> memberOf = new HashSet<>();

    public static class TeamMembership {
        private DateTime joinedOn;
        private Ref<Team> team;

        private TeamMembership() {
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the respective Python NDB mapping:

```python
class Person(ndb.Model):
    memberOf = ndb.StructuredProperty(TeamMembership, indexed=False, repeated=True)


class TeamMembership(ndb.Model):
    joinedOn = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=False)
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Team', indexed=False, repeated=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `LocalStructuredProperty`. NDB supports two ways of structuring data; `LocalStructuredProperty` corresponds to the java native `EmbeddedEntity` structure and works nicely.

The `StructuredProperty` format is a complicated beast that Objectify deprecated in v4.1 and abandoned entirely in v5.